# Need cement etching on inside floor?

Tags: sealing, cement, epoxy

I have a cement slab that had a plastic film and then pergo flooring. Removing this floor.
Right now, I just want to seal cement and epoxy paint once I get all pergo removed.
First, since I am only sealing do I need to degrease and etch the cement?
Second, can I epoxy paint over the sealed cement?

Answer (score 1):

Degrease and etch will help paint adhesion. the epoxy paint may be enough to seal the cement by itself, check the preparation instructions on the finish coat you have chosen.

Comment: I would agree. I have had excellent luck with epoxy paint on concrete has helped reduce moisture. I would always decrease & etch prior to trying to seal or epoxy paint or the material won't stick.+

Answer (score 1):

Diamond grinding is also something that is common for concrete floors these days.  I epoxy painted my garage floor and for preparation I had the floor ground with a diamond grinding machine.  It looks like a floor buffer, but rather than a polishing pad it has a disk with metal fins that are impregnated with diamonds.

This basically sands off the top thin layer of concrete and preps it for paint or other top coats.  The floor must be cleaned *very* well afterwards to remove dust, but no etching is needed since the surface of the concrete is already open.

Whichever route you take, for a long lasting epoxy or painted concrete surface, the preparation is the most important step.  Even a basic epoxy paint will last years with proper prep.

Comment: I am not taking pergo floor off all at one time. Therefore, would like to seal cement as I go along. Opening a cat shelter and am afraid cats will urinate on cement before sealed. It is not something I have time to do in one day. May take months. Can I paint epoxy on sealed cement?

Comment: The problem with paint or epoxy over the sealer is that they will only adhere as long as the sealer does.  Having a sealer immediately does sound like what you want to do, but unless you do the proper prep work before the paint, it just won't last as long.  What you can do is seal the floor a little at a time, then use a less expensive paint when the time comes and just plan on repainting (or at least touching up high traffic areas) every couple of years.

Comment: Once you take up the last of the pergo, you could then plan on grinding before the epoxy.  The grinder will remove all of the sealer on that part of the floor and give you a prepared, uniform surface for the paint.  Yes, it's an extra cost and time to spend, but it will save time and money down the road because the floor will last much longer.

Comment: I was afraid of that. JPhil. Does epoxy paint need to be put on at one time, or can I do sections as I pull up my pergo?

Comment: You can do sections, but there may be a noticeable line where the two sections meet (may not be a big deal).  And if you want to put down epoxy immediately, you would obviously not need sealer before.  And a good scrubbing/degreasing and etching will give decent results.  Grinding is the best, but it is honestly out of budget (money and time) for a lot of jobs.  The epoxy horror stories mostly come from people that do little other than a quick mopping before they paint and then wonder why it starts to peel in 9 months.

Comment: Thanx JPhi. Need to think more about this.